# How do I open up other missions?

Tags: pilota

In [Pilota](http://www.zsoltbartok.com/pilota.html), I completed the tutorial mission successfully, but now the other missions are still inaccessible in the menu.  All I can choose is free flight, and the tutorial again.

[image: Pilota mission selection]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

buy other planes to unlock missions

Comment: Once again, please elaborate. Yes this does answer the question, but for other users that might see this in future, might not even know how to buy planes. Try and describe the entire process that leads up to unlocking new missions.